# Zurb: Foundation Framework

Tags: javascript, css, html, zurb-foundation

I apologize, if this is extremely simple - I have created a webpage using the foundation framework(5.0) - it is very simplistic at the moment - and I am just looking for a way to define the height of elements on the page. If anyone could point me in the right direction it would be much appreciated.

Comment: Using a framework such as Foundation or Bootstrap requires some basic knowledge of HTML and CSS. You should look for introductory tutorials on those topics before digging into a framework.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to define the height of any element one simple way is to make a class for that element

```
<div class="high">
...
...
</div>
```

and in your stylesheet

```
.high{
height:x px;
}
```

replace x with the value you need.